# How can export special character with inkscape?

Tags: svg, pdf-generation, inkscape

I have some special characters ☎ in svg file, I use inkscape to export svg to pdf, but the special characters don't display.

Could you give me solutions for that?

Many thank.

Comment: I removed the itext tag because your question is not about iText. Also, your question appears not to be about programming, so it is better suited for another site in the StackExchange network, like SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of inkscape do you use? Writing a PDF at least in recent version is `save as`, not `export`, and uses PDF Cairo.

The issue you describe looks like a font issue, but current versions of inkscape embed the font in the PDF. Check in your PDF reader whether the font is embedded indeed (in document properties usually). Which PDF viewer do you use?

If issue continues and you don't mind a larger file, you can tick the box "Save texts as paths" in the Save as PDF dialog of inkscape. This is not ideal as all texts are converted but should work. Else you can manually convert the text containing the symbols using `Objet to path` in the `path` menu.

Comment: Thanks @Joce, when I upgrade inkscape to 0.91, I solved this problem.